# Tracking location based on distance and angle

Tags: c#, google-maps, gmap.net

I want to get the TM coordinates far from the first point (based on Google map).

The Google TM coordinates of the initial point can be retrieved via the API. Attach a picture to help you understand it.

1. Load Google map through Budapest's first TM coordinates (I did it with GMap).
2. I want to get the location of the next point in TM coordinates through distance and angle.

**Picture Example :**
[image]

Any ideas or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check this out :) https://github.com/anthonyvscode/LonelySharp/blob/master/LonelySharp/GeoLocation.cs

Comment: Check if you have access to the Geometry Library from Google Maps in gmap dot net. It has built-in methods to calculate areas, distances, headings, etc.